# Invalid token because of [ Unrecognized client. ] Google Sign in error

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-signin, google-plus-signin

I've been using this integration manual for server-side Google sign in for iOS: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started

and whenever I get the user to sign in and pass the id token to the back end server, this error comes up:

> Invalid token because of [ Unrecognized client. ]

I've obviously checked to see if my client is setup correctly and as far as I can see, it is. I've done the usual as seen below:

```
    GPPSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "some_code.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    GPPSignIn.sharedInstance().homeServerClientID = "some_code.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    GPPSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = [kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin]
    GPPSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GPPSignIn.sharedInstance().authenticate()

func finishedWithAuth(auth: GTMOAuth2Authentication!, error: NSError!) {

    sendPOSTRequest("https://url", params: "idToken=" + GPPSignIn.sharedInstance().idToken)
}

func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return GPPSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)
}
```

And I've added the URL Type with my bundle id mentioned in both the Identifier and URL Schemes fields.

I even went down the GIDSignIn route with the same result.